# jQuery selector to get all non-empty lists and print them

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Given the HTML below, what is the jQuery code to get all non-empty lists and print their list items?

```
<div id="list1" class="list">
  <ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="list2" class="list">
  <ul>
    <li>item 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="list3" class="list">
  <!-- intentionally empty -->
</div>
```

If possible, I'd like the selector to return only non-empty lists. In this example, the selector would return `list1` and `list2`, and then their values are printed: `[item 1, item 2, item 3], [item 4]`. I'm imagining something like this:

```
$('div .list [count(li) > 0]').each(function(items) { $.debug(items); });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
var $nonEmptyLists = $("ul:has(li)");
```

The above code selects "all ul elements that have at least 1 li child"

To print them:

```
$nonEmptyLists.each(function() { $.debug( this ); });
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this should do the trick : `$("ul:has(li)").each(...)`

**Update** : if you want to get the li's and not the ul's it should be more like

```
$("div.list ul:has(li) li").each(...)
```